# Passing objects to new window in quasar/electron

Tags: vue.js, electron, quasar, pinia

I have created an app using quasar and electron.js.
In my preload I call a new window using this:

```
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true,
      sandbox: false
    }
  })

  win.loadURL(process.env.APP_URL + '/#/newvessel/0')
```

this opens my Window correctly, but I need to send an object to my window.
I thought the easiest way would be by accessing my pinia store. Unfortunately my pinia store seems to only exist on a window to window basis.

Is there a simpler way to do this or am I doing something completely wrong?